# How to start a program using cmd in windows

Tags: java, mongodb, cmd

What i need is to accept a path (via args) to a mongod.cfg file and use it to start mongod from java. This is whar i am using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /k start mongod --config C:\\Users\\Ivan\\git\\StudentsDBMS_Server\\StudentsDBMS_Server\\mongod.bat");
```

And this is what i get
[image]

On removing **start** command it does not runs the command.
Also can you explain why does it prints the command infinitely but does not execute anyone of them.

Please

Comment: It seems you have a `mongod` batch file that calls `mongod`, that is, it calls itself over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank You MC ND and Riv,
The final command i used is

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /k start mongod --config \"C:\\Users\\pebble\\git\\StudentsDBMS_Server\\StudentsDBMS_Server\\mongod.cfg\"");
```

and i renamed *mongod.bat* to *mongoServer.bat*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the cmd syntax is off. Try like this maybe:

```
'cmd /k "start mongod --config C:\\Users\\Ivan\\git\\StudentsDBMS_Server\\StudentsDBMS_Server\\mongod.bat"'
```

Comment: It is giving the exact output as the screenshot.